# Filter data by java program or delete row in oracle db is more efficient?

Tags: java, oracle

I am thinking of inserting data to oracle db server using java program.
But before insert, the program have to filter the data in a .csv file and insert the filtered data.
But in my own, I think I can delete unwanted row after inserting all data and it seems more convenient to me.
Which approach should I use in case of long term or larger data set in terms of CPU/memory usage or time usage?
Thank you.

Comment: There is not enough information to really answer to this question. If you're inserting 100 rows and deleting 5 it probably doesn't matter. If you're inserting 1E9 records and deleting 90% of them it's a very different matter. The first question you should ask is why do you think it's going to matter? Don't worry about optimizing your solution until you know it's a problem.

Comment: As a general rule, I would avoid inserting data that is not supposed to be there in the first place. Other process could read it and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Committing a transaction that inserts a large number of rows in Oracle can take time because it involves writing on disk but also constraint checking, maybe triggers, table change notifications, etc. It will always be preferable to filter your data before doing the actual insert in Oracle.